# How to format a date using timezone in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, timestamp, nsdateformatter

I have checked other questions but none of them helped me much.

I have following string:

```
let dateString = "2018-04-29T21:00:00.000Z"
```

I have successfully converted it to date using the following:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let convertedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
```

But now I only want the time **"hh:mm a"** using **timezone** such as **"+8"**. I have tried following way but it's not working:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC+8")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
let requiredTime = dateFormatter.string(from: convertedDate!)
```

Can anyone help me to overcome this problem?

Comment: `hh:mm a Z`? - You can test it over at [nsdateformatter.com](http://nsdateformatter.com)

Comment: thanks, yes I am getting it like 2018-04-29 21:00:00 +0000 but I want to convert it as hh:mm a with time zone +8 which will be 9:00 pm + 8 = 5 am

Comment: How will I get it @MadProgrammer?

Comment: is it possible to add timezone +9 while formatting the dateString? @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you want is `hh:mm a Z`, which will provide the `+0800`.

You want to create a `TimeZone` which +8 hours from GMT, normally I prefer to use the appropriate abrivations (ie `AET`), but I guess if you don't have that, you can create a `TimeZone` using `secondsFromGMT`, for example...

```
let tz = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 8 * 60 * 60)
let toFormatter = DateFormatter()
toFormatter.timeZone = tz
toFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a Z"
let requiredTime = toFormatter.string(from: convertedDate!)
```

Which based on your example data, will produce a value of...

```
05:00 AM +0800
```

Comment: yeah this worked but what if the timezone will change like -6 or +6 or +8 or -8

Comment: 60 seconds in a minute, 60 minutes in an hour ... pretty sure you can see where the change might need to be made here

Comment: thanks a lot. for curiosity, when I am converting the string to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ this then is it possible to add timezone into this?

Comment: The `String` value already has a `TimeZone` associated with it. `Date` is just a container for the number of seconds since a specific point in time (in most cases, the Unix Epoch), so, they tend to be agnostic when it comes to time zones - when formatting the `Date`, we use a `TimeZone` to provide human readable context to `String` value